# Bulk convert DBF to CSV in a folder ArcGIS 10.1 using Python

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, arcpy, csv, dbf

I would like to convert 1000 dbf files to CSV. All dbf files are in one folder and they have sequential names (S:\output_tables\tcb1.dbf, S:\output_tables\tcb2.dbf, S:\output_tables\tcb3.dbf, up to S:\output_tables\tcb1000.dbf).

I would like S:\output_tables\1.csv, S:\output_tables\2.csv, S:\output_tables\3.csv up to S:\output_tables\1000.csv

I would like to eventually run in a ARCGIS 10.1 model so ArcPy would be the preferred solution but I'm open to other options.

Comment: DBF is a part of a shapefile and is a very common GIS component and once operational I would like to run in a GIS model as part of a larger GIS process.

Comment: Are ALL of the DBFs you are talking about associated with shapefiles, or only some, or none?

Comment: A mixture or I would use the 'Export Features to ASCII tool'. I can do them as two batches I suppose one with the tool and one with code but it would be nice for the model to have them as one single ArcPy script.

Comment: why not just convert them with ogr2ogr in a shell script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have only tested this very briefly (and with a limited variety of data), but this script demonstrates one way this might be accomplished:

```
import arcpy
import csv
import os
import codecs
import cStringIO

def batch_convert_dbf_to_csv(input_dir, output_dir, rename_func=None):
    """Converts shapefiles and standalone DBF tables within the input directory
    input_dir to CSV files within the output directory output_dir. An
    optional function rename_func may be used to manipulate the output file
    name."""
    # Set workspace to input directory
    arcpy.env.workspace = input_dir

    # List shapefiles and standalone DBF tables in workspace
    tables = list_tables()

    # Only proceed if there actually exists one or more shapefiles or DBF tables
    if tables:
        # Create output directory structure
        make_output_dir(output_dir)

        # Loop over shapefiles and DBF tables
        for table in tables:
            # Generate output filename
            output_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(table))[0]
            if rename_func:
                output_name = rename_func(output_name)
            output_csv_file = os.path.join(output_dir,
                output_name + os.extsep + 'csv')

            # List input fields
            fields = list_fields(table)

            # Open input table for reading
            rows = read_rows(table, fields)

            # Set flag indicating whether we are overwriting an existing file
            output_exists = os.path.isfile(output_csv_file)

            # Attempt to create output CSV file
            try:
                write_unicode_csv(output_csv_file, rows, fields)

                # Warn if we overwrite anything
                if output_exists:
                    print 'warning: overwrote {0}'.format(output_csv_file)
                else:
                    print 'wrote {0}'.format(output_csv_file)
            except IOError:
                print 'warning: unable to create output CSV file {0}'.format(
                    output_csv_file)
    else:
        print 'No DBF files found in workspace {0}'.format(input_dir)

def list_tables():
    """Returns a list of shapefiles and standalone DBF tables in the current
    workspace."""
    tables = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*.shp')
    tables.extend(arcpy.ListTables('*', 'dBASE'))
    return tables

def list_fields(table):
    """Returns a list of fields in the specified table, excluding the shape
    field if present."""
    desc = arcpy.Describe(table)
    shape_field_name = desc.shapeFieldName if hasattr(
        desc, 'shapeFieldName') else ''
    return [field.name for field in desc.fields
        if field.name != shape_field_name]

def read_rows(table, fields='*'):
    """Generator function that yields the rows of a table, including only the
    specified fields."""
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table, fields) as rows:
        for row in rows:
            yield row

def write_unicode_csv(output_csv, rows, header_row=None):
    """Creates a UTF-8 encoded CSV file specified by output_csv containing the
    specified rows and the optional header_row."""
    with open(output_csv, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8) # Write Byte Order Mark character so Excel
                                 # knows this is a UTF-8 file
        csv_writer = UnicodeWriter(f, dialect='excel', encoding='utf-8')
        if header_row:
            csv_writer.writerow(header_row)
        csv_writer.writerows(rows)

def make_output_dir(path):
    """Creates the output directory structure if it does not already exist."""
    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        try:
            os.makedirs(path)
            print 'created dir {0}'.format(path)
        except OSError:
            if not os.path.isdir(path):
                raise

class UnicodeWriter:
    """
    A CSV writer which will write rows to CSV file 'f',
    which is encoded in the given encoding.
    Based on: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples
    """

    def __init__(self, f, dialect=csv.excel, encoding='utf-8', **kwds):
        # Redirect output to a queue
        self.queue = cStringIO.StringIO()
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.queue, dialect=dialect, **kwds)
        self.stream = f
        self.encoder = codecs.getincrementalencoder(encoding)()

    def writerow(self, row):
        self.writer.writerow([str(s).encode('utf-8') for s in row])
        # Fetch UTF-8 output from the queue ...
        data = self.queue.getvalue()
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        # ... and reencode it into the target encoding
        data = self.encoder.encode(data)
        # write to the target stream
        self.stream.write(data)
        # empty queue
        self.queue.truncate(0)

    def writerows(self, rows):
        for row in rows:
            self.writerow(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Configure script here, or modify to take parameters/arguments
    input_dir = r'path\to\input_directory'
    output_dir = r'path\to\output_directory'

    # Customize this function to change renaming logic
    def rename_func(input_name, default='output'):
        # Strips non-digits from string
        output_name = ''.join((char for char in input_name if char.isdigit()))

        # Give filename a sensible default name if there are no digits
        return output_name or default

    # Run it
    batch_convert_dbf_to_csv(input_dir, output_dir, rename_func)
```

This does not take any arguments/parameters so I leave that up to you. If you want to implement it as a [script tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000006000000) or [Python toolbox](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001500000022000000), read the appropriate ESRI documentation.

It attempts some defensive coding techniques for things like mixed shapefile and standalone DBF content, omitting `Shape` fields, non-ASCII characters, non-existent directories, warning when it overwrites existing files, etc., but as I said, not well tested, so use at your own risk!

Answer (score 6):

This should work for both shapefile and separate dbf file

```
import os
import arcpy
import csv

def dbf2csv(dbfpath, csvpath):
    ''' To convert .dbf file or any shapefile/featureclass to csv file
    Inputs: 
        dbfpath: full path to .dbf file [input] or featureclass
        csvpath: full path to .csv file [output]

    '''
    #import csv
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(dbfpath)
    csvFile = csv.writer(open(csvpath, 'wb')) #output csv
    fieldnames = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(dbfpath)]

    allRows = []
    for row in rows:
        rowlist = []
        for field in fieldnames:
            rowlist.append(row.getValue(field))
        allRows.append(rowlist)

    csvFile.writerow(fieldnames)
    for row in allRows:
        csvFile.writerow(row)
    row = None
    rows = None
```

Call this function dbf2csv for every dbf file
In your case 1000 times, this is just an example of calling, perhaps it will work for you without any modification

```
dbf_dir = 'S:/output_tables/'
csv_dir = 'S:/output_tables/csv1/'
for dbf_file in os.listdir(dbf_dir):
    # Loop through all dbf files
    # and export to dbf
    fileName, fileExt = os.path.splitext(dbf_file)  #[0] or [1] for file
    if '.dbf' in fileExt:
        # construct full path to dbf file and csv file
        dbfpath = os.path.join(dbf_dir, fileName+fileExt)
        csvpath = os.path.join(csv_dir, fileName+'.csv')
        if os.path.exists(dbfpath):
            # this may not be necessary
            #    print 'processing: ', dbfpath, csvpath                    
            if not os.path.exists(csvpath):
                ## to prevent overwrite of existing csv file
                ## call the function to convert .dbf file to csv file
                print 'Export nexrad {0} to {1}'.format(dbfpath, csvpath)
                dbf2csv(dbfpath, csvpath)
```

Since it this python, make sure the indentations are right

Comment: Nice solution - this was the only one I could get to work for me.

Comment: Beautiful solution, but it may be necessary to drop the 'b' from 'wb' in the function if you get "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'".

Answer (score 3):

If you look for a full arcpy solution (without dbf) you can use

```
import glob
glob.glob('S:\\output_tables\\*.dbf')
```

for listing you tables, then

```
arcpy.ListFields()
```

for the field names and

```
outname = os.path.basename(inputtable)[3:-4] + ".csv"
```

to create your output names

and finally

```
arcpy.da.SearchCursor()
```

to get a Python iterable that you can use directly with csv.writerow() (and even with csv.writerows() to e verified)

Comment: Based on my testing, `ListTables()` will not list DBFs associated with shapefiles. So you'll have to either combine this with `ListFeatureClasses()`,  or use `ListFiles()` or Python's `glob()` or `listdir()` functions.

Comment: You're right, I'll change that

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best solution I have found thus far using dbfpy and arcpy.

```
import arcpy
from dbfpy import dbf
from arcpy import env

def DBFtoCSV():
    '''Convert every DBF table into CSV table. 
    '''
    env.workspace = pathlist[1] # Set new workplace where tables are located 
    tablelist = arcpy.ListTables() # list tables in file
    for table in tablelist: # iterate through every table
        #make sure you are just working with .dbf tables 
        if table.endswith('.dbf'):
            #name csv the same as the .dbf table just with .csv at the end
            csv_fn = table[:-4]+ ".csv"
            with open(pathlist[2]+csv_fn,'wb') as csvfile: # name output path
                in_db = dbf.Dbf(pathlist[1]+table)
                out_csv = csv.writer(csvfile)
                #copy row names and items in rows from dbf to csv
                names = []
                for field in in_db.header.fields:
                    names.append(field.name)
                out_csv.writerow(names)
                for rec in in_db:
                    out_csv.writerow(rec.fieldData)
                in_db.close()
        #keep track of processing
        print "\n Processing ",table[:-4]+".csv table complete."
```