# ArcGIS 10. Convert dbf to csv or similar in ArcPy without cursors

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, convert, csv, dbf

I have many dbf's created by the Spatial Analyst Sample tool.
I would like to convert those dbf's into csv's or space delimited (or any text for that matter).
I can't seem to find the ArcPy equivalent of "Right click table > Data > Export"

There are a few ideas I saw, which include the use of cursors:
[Exporting table to XYZ ASCII file via ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17933/exporting-table-to-xyz-ascii-file-via-arcpy)
and
[Bulk convert DBF to CSV in a folder ArcGIS 10.1 using Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93303/bulk-convert-dbf-to-csv-in-a-folder-arcgis-10-1-using-python)

Is there anything simpler and quicker? 
My tables have over 3 million rows each.
I did see the mention of "arcpy.ExportXYv_stats", but that fails with input table is not recognized format etc.

Alternatively, where can I find their dbf specifications? 
Fortran should be faster.

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to use either the [Copy Rows](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//0017000000n4000000) tool or the [Table to Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000027000000) tool to get the job done. Just make sure to give your `out_table`/`out_name` parameter ends with '.csv' and you should have no trouble.

**EDIT:** Due to another inexplicable Esri oversight, these tools do in fact force you to save as DBF if you're saving outside of a geodatabase. I maintain that you *should* be able to use those tools to achieve this, but at this point (ArcGIS 10.2.2) you can't. If it were me, I guess I would end up using an `arcpy.da.SearchCursor` (as in [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17933/exporting-table-to-xyz-ascii-file-via-arcpy)), which are much faster than the old `arcpy.SearchCursor`.

Comment: Great thanks for that suggestion. However no matter what extension I use, that tool outputs a dbf. Here's what I use: `infil="2010_LC_xyz.dbf"
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(infil, outpath, "test.csv") `. I am now going to try and use http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbfpy/ so I just manipulate the dbf directly in Python.